# PHP outputting numbers in exponential form

Tags: php, transformation, exponential

When i'm outputting some of my double variables they're being written in exponential form using fwrite. Can i set some defaults in PHP where whenever a variable is displayed (copied or stored) it always happens in decimal format?

To be precise the problem occurs when i use the json_decode method on a json string which contains a double value (which is not in exponential form). That double value after converting an an object becomes exponential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the numbers are still floats when being written (as opposed to strings), this is one way of doing it:

```
echo rtrim(sprintf("%0.15f", $x), "0.");
```

I'm not sure if there's a cleaner way or not. But basically this uses `sprintf` to print a maximum of 15 decimal places, and then trims off any trailing `0` or `.` chars. (Of course, there's no guarantee that everything will be rounded nicely with trailing zeros as you might expect.)

If you just want a fixed size, then you can adjust the `15` and remove the `rtrim`.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem where `json_decode` was converting recent twitter/tweet IDs into exponential numbers.

I solved it by upping PHP's float precision, which can be done a different few ways...

- find the `precision` value in your php.ini and change it to `precision = 20`
- add `ini_set('precision', 20);` to your PHP app
- add `php_value precision 20` to your app's .htaccess or virtual host file

Otherwise, if you're fine with having your `BIGINT` converted to a string and you have PHP 5.3+ you can also pass a flag to `json_decode` like so: `json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)`

Comment: In fact: `5.4.0  The options parameter was added.` - so it's 5.4+ But the precision thing - that's a great idea :)